# setting up global gcp vm

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I need help setting up VM using GCP,  this is my first VM on GCP

How can I set it up so anyone that has username@IP and password to be able to login

i.e   (ssh user@IP password)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, log into the VM using `gcloud compute ssh VM_NAME` or web ssh(by clicking `ssh` on the GCP console.

Then edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes` and restart sshd service: `systemctl restart sshd`

After that, you can add user and grant password `adduser testuser`

Then you can use username and password to log into the VM: `ssh testuser@PUBLIB_IP_OF_VM`